# unresolved external symbol error. dumpbin shows extra @number appended to symbols

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, linker-errors

My knowledge is C is very limited. I am trying to upgrade a library used in my project. I replaced the old static library and header file with the updated files. When I try to build my project, I am getting the "unresolved external symbol" error.

I inspected both the old and new lib files using dumpbin and found that the symbols in the new library has an extra @number (where number is one of 8, 16, 24, 28, 32, 40, 48, 52, 72 or 80) appended. Can someone please tell me how to proceed?

**Update**

The error stopped somehow. But now I am getting the error

> LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll)

I [tried adding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267384%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.lib` to the compiler options for the library. But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols appended with the `@` symbol and a number are functions that use the `stdcall` [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).  It would appear you are compiling the new library with `stdcall` as the default instead of `cdecl`.

Look in the header file at the function declarations.  You will most likely see something indicating this alternate calling convention. If you do not and you are sure the static library you have matches the header file you could update the [function declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) in the header file to include the `stdcall` calling convention.  Then when compiling your program that uses the static library the symbols in your program will correctly look for the `stdcall` style function symbols.

Addressing **Update**

This is probably a conflict with what you are linking your static library to and what you are linking your final binary to.  Both your static library and your final program binary must link against the same C runtime.

Comment: The functions are declared like `ext_def(char *) swe_version(char *);` where ext_def(x) is macro `#define ext_def(x) extern EXP32 x FAR PASCAL_CONV EXP16`

Comment: In new library EXP32 is `#define EXP32  __declspec( dllexport )` and in old one it was `#define EXP32`.

Comment: I would look at the `PASCAL_CONV` macro.  The pascal calling convention is no longer supported.  Try changing `FAR PASCAL_CONV` to `WINAPI`.  `WINAPI` is defined in `Windows.h`.

Comment: The old PASCAL calling convention has been replaced by stdcall.  Which is okay btw, it is the most common one for exported DLL functions.

Comment: I am sorry, that macro was for DLL and I am building static library.

Comment: I compared the header files and build output for both the libraries. The header files are almost the same (other than a few minor logic changes) and the project / compiler properties from the buildlog also matches. And somehow the unresolved symbols error is also gone.

Comment: The you surely shouldn't use "ext_def" on the functions.  Or change the macro.

Comment: For static library the macro was just `#define EXP32`

Comment: For a static library that makes sense.  There is no need to export it.